# How do I catch user saving unsaved document in Word 2013 / Word 2016 before user get to the File > Save As pane?

Tags: ms-word

For an unsaved/new document In Word 2010 the Application DocumentBeforeSave event is raised in the moment the user choose File > Save or File > Save As (or any button or keyboard short-cut leading to the same).
If one trap this event one can do custom save actions then set Cancel to True and user is still viewing the document never having seen any Word Save As dlg/panes etc.

In Word 2016 (and presumably also in Word 2013) the DocumentBeforeSave event is raised only when user select/click on any of the links provided in the Save As pane.
Also after trapping the event and doing custom save actions and setting Cancel to True user is left with the Save As pane.
[image]

Anyone having any idéa as to how one can get Word 2010 behaviour for this?

Comment: I am using C++, not VSTO, to load a C# Word Add-in at startup which in turn traps the DocumentBeforeSave event. Anyhow this does not matter, one will find the exact same issue if one try to use VBA.

Comment: I believe your C# Word Add-in would need to provide Ribbon XML that changes the File menu, hiding the built-in SaveAs and replacing it with a custom one that would call the code you want.

Comment: Trouble with using Ribbon XML (backstage) to replace built-in SaveAs is that this can only be done when an instance of Word is starting and cannot be changed while it is running. It is not possible (as far as I've found) to change visibility of backstage items with mso id (idMso) during runtime.

Comment: Yes, but if you're replacing it that shouldn't matter?

Answer (score 0):

Word 2016: Go to File > Options > Save and tick the "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files":

[image: Preventing Backstage from showing when pressing Ctrl-S or any other short-cut for saving a document the first time.]

To test the effect of this using VBA:

Create class:

```
Public WithEvents wApp As Word.Application
Private Sub wApp_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal wDoc As Document, _
   saveAsUi As Boolean, cancel As Boolean)
   If MsgBox("Save?", vbYesNo, "Custom save") = vbNo Then cancel = True
End Sub
```

Create module:

```
Dim myClass As New Class1
Sub Test()
 Set myClass.wApp = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Run Test() then try to save unsaved document using Ctrl-S (or some other short-cut). Now you should get "Custom save" dlg.

If "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files" is not ticked off pressing Ctrl-S should lead the File > Save As Tab in Backstage (as described in the question).

The improvment with this solution compared to replacing the built-in Save As with our own using ribbon (backstage) xml is that user will still be able to get to the built-in Save As by using File > Save As.

*Now, another question is: Is it possible to send the user on to the built-in File > Save As depending on which document is active?*

Stein-Tore